# How can I test a variable resistor, while it is still in the circuit board?

Tags: inverter, resistance-measurement

How can I test a variable resistor, in the circuit? It is a 6p1 102, The ohms I am getting are approximately 1700 ohms. Is this normal for still being on the PC board? Adjustment knob appears to be glued in place,I do not want to turn it until I remove it from the circuit.Then i will be able to test the actual resistance.

Comment: Have you seen how this "variable resistor" is connected - really as a 2-terminal variable resistor (rheostat) or as a 3-terminal potentiometer?

Comment: It is a 3 terminal component.It is grounded on 1 terminal,the other 2 terminals have the resistance on the neutral line for the A/C output.

Comment: I have asked you because I have an idea to indirectly measure the resistance if there is a resistor with a known resistance R in series: When the power is on, the voltage drop V across the resistor R is measured and the current I = V/R is determined according to Ohm's law. Then the voltage drop Vp on the potentiometer is measured and the resistance R = Vp/Rp is calculated again according to Ohm's law.

Comment: Another tip: Mark the wiper position and then experiment with it by measuring the voltage drops between the middle and end terminals. They must change (cross-fade) in the opposite direction from zero to maximum. Finally, restore the wiper position.

Comment: Thank you I will try that

Answer (score 5):

10**2** means it’s a 1kOhm potentiometer (10**00**). With a good potentiometer you’ll never measure more than 1k between its pins, if the board capacitors are fully discharged.

You’ll measure higher than 1k if there are charged capacitors in the circuit, or if the potentiometer is damaged.

If you measure 1k or less, then the potentiometer may be ok - or not, depending on what other resistances and semiconductor junctions are connected in parallel.

To check for charged capacitors, use a voltmeter to measure voltages between the pins of the potentiometer when the power is turned off. The voltages should be zero, as-if you shorted the multimeter probes together.

Answer (score 3):

If you measure the resistance from the wiper to either end of the track, you should see the resistance drop to zero (or a few ohms) when the wiper is moved to that end of the track.  There are failure modes, eg intermittent contact, where a faulty pot would pass this test, but it gives a quick guide.

Comment: The pot in question is on a power inverter board. It appears to be factory set,it is in the neutral a/c output line.Would 1700 ohms possibly be an issue?

Comment: Without knowing about the rest of the circuit it’s difficult to say.